# Good manners in Temple

Tags: japan, temples

I'm going to Japan next week and I booked a night in a temple.

I would like know some of best manners. I think a temple is a quiet place, look like a church. I believe not make noise is one important.

Someone who has experience with japan can help me with some tips. Because the difference between culture ocidental and oriental, I believe some mistakes are more normal from the people from ocident.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: **Don't worry about it**.

I've stayed in lots of temples and shrines in Japan, and their accommodations are effectively identical to "secular" Japanese inns: for example, you'll be offered alcohol with meals, and boisterous drinking parties for traveling groups are not uncommon, particularly in Shinto shrine lodges.  Of course, the [usual rules of Japanese indoor etiquette](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan#Ryokan) apply, so take off your shoes before walking on tatami etc.

Only a few points may remind you that you are, in fact, in a temple:

- The staff are mostly (but not necessarily entirely) monks.
- The food will mostly likely be vegetarian.
- You may be offered the chance to join the morning service (Shingon sect) or meditation session (Zen sects like Soto/Rinzai). If you accept, and you should even though it usually involves waking up at 5 AM, literally *all* you need to do is sit there quietly and watch.

Comment: I can confirm, my experience was pretty much the same except we didn't have any alcohol :-(